# PhoneGap not loading images from HTTP

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap app. I started it using `phonegap create my-app`, and developed much of the UI. Then, I realized I'd need some Java code, so I created a new ADT project [according to these instructions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html) and copied my HTML/CSS/JavaScript into the `assets/www` folder.

The UI works now, except for one thing. I'm making requests to [RoboHash](http://robohash.org) to generate avatars, and that was working before I moved to ADT. Now, the entire UI works, but I get broken-image icons where my avatars were before. **What do I have to change about my project to get images working?**

[image: RoboHash example]

Note: I do have `android.permission.INTERNET` declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might missed the following access rule in **config.xml** file:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

Comment: Thanks! One of the things I like about Cordova is that you can use `$.ajax()` to access any web endpoint regardless of origin. Never occurred to me there'd be a control on this!